# Can I'm get part of mongo document by find conditions?

Tags: mongodb

I have a foo collection with many documents. 
For example:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("51c46dc75d1e56f582940c9c"),
"name" : "John",
"age" : 25,
"address" : {
    "city" : "New York",
    "postalCode" : "10021"
},
"phones" : [
    {
        "phone" : "212-555-1234",
        "type" : "home"
    },
    {
        "phone" : "646-555-1234",
        "type" : "mobile"
    }
]
```

}

Can I find document without all phones in phones array? For example - mongo return document with phones.type = "mobile". I'm want get John's document without included phones with "home" type?

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("51c46dc75d1e56f582940c9c"),
"name" : "John",
"age" : 25,
"address" : {
    "city" : "New York",
    "postalCode" : "10021"
},
"phones" : [
    {
        "phone" : "646-555-1234",
        "type" : "mobile"
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this with simple **find**, but you can use aggregation framework:

```
db.<coll>.aggregate({$match:{"name" : "John"}}, {$unwind:"$phones"}, {$match:{"phones.type":'mobile'}})
```

where  is your collections with phones

**UPD**

Thank to @asya-kamsky for information. Here is version with **$elemMatch**, but I don't want to steal your opportunity to think by yourself. I made a spoiler, if you totally lost with this question:

> db..find({'name': 'John'},{phones:{ $elemMatch:{"type": "mobile"}}, name:1, age:1, address:1}).pretty()

Comment: Thank you so much! I already finish only first week of mongo developer school, but this question expected answer today)

Comment: your grade may suffer as this is not the correct answer, nor is it the answer expected by your instructor.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this when executing `find` by providing a second argument which is called the projection - that is where you specify which parts (fields) of the document you want returned.  This is somewhat analogous to SQL where you don't normally say `SELECT *` but rather enumerate the columns you actually want returned.

Since this is an array that you only want to get a single matching element from, you will need to [use the `$elemMatch` projection operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/projection/elemMatch/).

Since this is your homework, I will leave it to you to construct the actual `find` now that you know how it's supposed to be done.